# Proof of the open interval $(-1,1)$ with respect to $*$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

[image: The problem]

[image: The solution]

Hi,so I  just can't get my head through the solution for 4th problem.I successfully proved associative law and when I wrote an equation for finding identity element I did get the same thing,but then I don't understand how they get $e(1 - x^2) = 0$. I always get $x + e = x^2e + x$.

I'd appreciate if someone could explain. I understand that logically speaking, it should be $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $e$ be the identity element. Then

$$x*e=x=e*x=\frac{x+e}{xe+1}$$ so, $x(xe+1)=x+e$ and so $x^2e+x=x+e$ which implies $$e-x^2e=0$$ that is, $$e(1-x^2)=0$$ and so $e=0$

Verification: $$x*0=\frac{x+0}{x.0+1}=x=0*x$$

Added: To find the inverse of an arbitrary $x$, assume $y$ is the inverse of $x$. That is, $$x*y=0=\frac{x+y}{xy+1}$$

Therefore, numerator must be zero and so $y=-x$

Comment: _thank you soo much!_

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative solution. I'm sure not everyone will like it.

Observe that
$$\tanh(a+b)=\frac{\tanh a+\tanh b}{1+\tanh a\tanh b}.$$
Therefore
$$x*y=\tanh\left(\tanh^{-1}x+\tanh^{-1}y\right).\tag{*}$$

From (*) one can read off associativity easily:
\begin{align}
x*(y*z)&=\tanh(\tanh^{-1}x+\tanh^{-1}(y*z))\\
&=\tanh(\tanh^{-1}x+(\tanh^{-1}y+\tanh^{-1}z))\\
&=\cdots=(x*y)*z.
\end{align}
Since $0$ is the additive identity and $\tanh 0=0$ then $0$
is the identity for $*$. Also
$$x*(-x)=\tanh(\tanh^{-1}x+\tanh^{-1}(-x))
=\tanh(\tanh^{-1}x-\tanh^{-1}x)=\tanh0=0$$
etc.

Comment: Lol I didn't expected a trigonometric approach. Very creative!! :)

Comment: ike it! Shark it! :+)

Comment: _couldn't understood this now, but i hope i will someday thanks !_